# python encryption and decryption by using file

Tags: python

I am currently working on encrypting and decrypting files using python and I got to this part. I should replace original file with encryption dictionary and I tried to do so, but when I read the file and write it, it shows original text and encrypt version of it.

My original file contains the text, ABCDEF, and what I got for the result is **ABCDEFGH!@#$%^&*.**

So I am not sure how to get rid of the original text.

Here is my code

```
import os

Dictionary = {'A':'!','B':'@','C':'#','D':'$','E':'%','F':'^'}

letterfile = input("What's the name of the file?")

exist = os.path.exists(letterfile)

if exist:

    letterfile = open(letterfile, "r+")

    readfile = letterfile.read()

    for i in readfile:

        if i in Dictionary:

            letterfile.write(Dictionary[i])
    
    letterfile.close()
```

Comment: You should close the file and reopen it for writing to replace the contents.

Answer (score 0):

You don't rewind to the beginning of the file when you write, so you're writing where the reading finished, which is the end of the file.

The right way to do this is to reopen the file for writing. That will empty the file and replace it with the encrypted version.

```
with open(letterfile, "r") as infile:
    readfile = infile.read()

with open(letterfile, "w") as outfile:
    for i in readfile:
        letterfile.write(Dictionary.get(i, ""))
```

Comment: okay so we have to open the file again and then we can get rid of the original text, this makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

one way you can accomplish this by putting `letterfile.truncate(0)` after
`readfile = letterfile.read()` and before `for i in readfile:`

fully it would look like this

```
import os

Dictionary = {'A':'!','B':'@','C':'#','D':'$','E':'%','F':'^'}

letterfile = input("What's the name of the file?")

exist = os.path.exists(letterfile)

if exist:

    letterfile = open(letterfile, "r+")

    readfile = letterfile.read()
    letterfile.truncate(0)
    for i in readfile:

        if i in Dictionary:

            letterfile.write(Dictionary[i])
    
    letterfile.close()
```

Comment: If we truncate, wouldn't it just get rid of all the text in the file?

Comment: @qorhvk yes it would but thats why its between the readfile and the for loop by then the readfile varible would already have all the txt files data saved so it is still able to run the for loop and then write in the new letters

Comment: Oh okay that makes sense now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You also need `letterfile.seek(0)`. Otherwise you'll leave a large gap at the beginning of the file where the original contents were.